# toggle textfield enabled and disabled

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to disable and enable a textbox using a checkbox. I have this code, but the problem is, when I checked the checkbox the textbox gets enabled. However, when I unchecked it, it doesn't get disabled again. could anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

```js
function toggleDIOthers(opt) {
  if (opt == 'DIOthers')
    document.getElementById('DIOthers').disabled = false;
  else
    document.getElementById('DIOthers').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="DIOthers" onClick="toggleDIOthers('DIOthers')"  name="types_house[]"
  {if in_array('DIOthers', $data.house)}
    checked
  {/if}
 >Others:</label>
  <input type="text" id="DIOthers" disabled class="form-control" name="types_house_others" required value="{$data['houseOthers']}">
</div>
```

If the checkbox is checked i want to make the textbox required.

Comment: Your `if` is checking whether the user has clicked that specific checkbox, but the rest of the function reads as if you had checked whether it's checked or not. You need a nested 2nd `if` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the element as parameter and check its value like this:

```js
function toggleDIOthers(opt, elt) {
  if (opt == 'DIOthers'){
    document.getElementById('DIOthers').disabled = !elt.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="DIOthers" onClick="toggleDIOthers('DIOthers', this)"  name="types_house[]"
  {if in_array('DIOthers', $data.house)}
    checked
  {/if}
 >Others:</label>
  <input type="text" id="DIOthers" disabled class="form-control" name="types_house_others" required value="{$data['houseOthers']}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function to toggle the disable attribute by the oposite of what it currently is.

```js
function toggleDIOthers() {
  var textbox = document.getElementById('DIOthers');
  textbox.disabled = !textbox.disabled;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="DIOthers" onClick="toggleDIOthers()"  name="types_house[]"
  {if in_array('DIOthers', $data.house)}
    checked
  {/if}
 >Others:</label>
  <input type="text" id="DIOthers" disabled class="form-control" name="types_house_others" required value="{$data['houseOthers']}">
</div>
```

Comment: You are not checking the checkbox value, so this could be desynchronized if something else acts on the `disabled` attribute

Comment: @Twistingnether if something else acts on the `disabled` attribute of the checkbox, it will not update the textbox in both our cases, and therefore your click of the checkbox will do nothing. There are lots of limitations, this is just a simple answer.